# Working with arrays and sets in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table. One of its columns is of type `array<string>`. I try to run a query on this table and then load the data in a file.

This is the query

```
Select concat(key, '|'
  , code, '|'
  , round(sum(amt), 4), '|'
  , count(*)
  , collect_set(comment))
from test_agg
where TIME_KEY = '2017-02-19'
group by key, code;
```

But get an error

```
FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<string> was passed as parameter 1.
```

I understand that I can't pass the function a `array<string>`, but what can I do?

`comment` is the column of type `array<string>`

This is how I run it.

```
hive -f CALC_FILE.sql > 20170220.txt
```

Comment: P.s. - The best way to get a good a fast good answer is to supply the `show create table` and a data sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `concat_ws` to convert the `comment` array to string, concatenate the `collect_set` results and than concatenate it to the rest of the columns

```
select      concat_ws
            (
                '|'
               ,key
               ,code
               ,round(sum(amt),4)
               ,count(*) 
               ,concat_ws('<<<>>>',collect_set(ws_concat('~~~',comment)))
            )

from        test_agg

where       time_key = '2017-02-19'

group by    key
           ,code
;
```

Comment: It was useful, but didn't solve the problem. The problem is that `comment` is of type array<string>. It is bassicaly `collect_set(collect_set(some_column))`. So the error still pops out. I would like to know if there is a way of splitting `collect_set(some_column)` into strings, so that I can then again collect the values. Or maybe there is a way of splitting a string val1, val2, so that when grouping by key and code I can get only the unic values.

Comment: P.s. You might consider using `collect_list` instead of `collect_set`

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
Select concat(key, '|'
  , code, '|'
  , round(sum(amt), 4), '|'
  , count(*)
  , collect_set(comment[0]))
from test_agg
where TIME_KEY = '2017-02-19'
group by key, code;
```